# How I pasert thhis JSON with JAVA

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert JSON to JAVA, using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`, but I'm not being able to convert the windows object with no names:

[ERROR]:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `ex.Item` out of START_ARRAY token
     at [Source: (String)"{...}"; line: 4, column: 3] (through reference chain: ex.Example["windows"]->java.lang.Object[][0])
```

Can some one help me ?

Comment: Your answer solve nothing, because we don't know the problem^^

Comment: Creating a self-answer is helpful, but please be sure to clearly describe the problem so that the Q&A is maximally useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON]:

```
{
    "metric": "approved_documents",
    "windows": [
        [
            null
        ],
        [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "summary": 1,
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "summary": 1,
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

[Example.java]

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("metric")
    private String metric;
    @JsonProperty("windows")
    private Item[] windows;
    public String getMetric() {return metric;}
    public void setMetric(String metric) {this.metric = metric;}
    public Item[] getWindows() {return windows;}
    public void setWindows(Item[] windows) {this.windows = windows;}

}
```

[Item.java]:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Item {

    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private String quantity;

}
```

[TEST]:

```
@Test
public void example() throws Exception {
    mapper().readValue(ResourceReader.read("example.json"), Example[].class);
}
```